# A Sneaky Yin-Yang Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

*Here is a standard Yin-Yang puzzle.*

**Rules of Yin-Yang**:

1. Fill each empty cell with either a black circle or a white circle.
2. All white circles should be orthogonally connected, so do all black circles.
3. There may not be any 2x2 cell region consisting of the same circle color.

---

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I couldn't find a suitable starting logic without a not-well-known trick:

> In a puzzle with even width and height, the border cells excluding the corners are divided into dominoes, each of  which is to be colored in a single color. So the bottom left corner starts as this: 
>  [image]

> Apply some easy deduction and use the "border pair" logic once more: 
>  [image]

> Some more easy deduction, and we realize that the white must go all around the board by border connectivity logic. Sneaky! 
> [image] 
>  [image]

> Then the chain of easy deduction finishes the puzzle: 
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

Comment: "Fill each empty cell with either a black circle or a white circle." ;-)

Comment: @Florian I believe that has been left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Correct and well done! :D (The technique is apparently mentioned way back then here in PSE: [A problem about Yin-Yang puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/53193/28719))

Comment: @athin Yeah, I learned it through that exact post :)